# Angular JS: Sort Grid Contents based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop down button in my headerCellTemplate that looks like this

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown">
        <b>Value</b><span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="position:fixed;top:inherit;left:320px;">
        <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On click it is it suppose to sort the ng grid contents. I have written the code that can sort the grid contents from H-M-L. the function looks like this

```
var result = 1;
var test="HML";
function impSortFn(a, b) {
    a=test.indexOf(a);
    b=test.indexOf(b);
    if (a == b) return 0;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return result;
}
```

And the column Defs looks like this

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        field:'dt', displayName:'Date',  width:'***',
        cellFilter:'date:\"dd-MMM-yyyy\"', headerClass:'grad1',
        cellTemplate:'<div><center>{{row.getProperty(\'dt\')|dateformat}}</center></div>'
    },
    {
        field:'dt', displayName:'Time',  width:'**',
        cellFilter:'date:\"HH:mm:ss\"', headerClass:'grad1',
        cellTemplate:'<div><center>{{row.getProperty(\'dt\')|timefilter}}</center></div>'
    },
    {
        field:'rl', displayName:'Impact',width:'80px',
        sortFn:impSortFn, headerClass:'grad1', headerCellTemplate:"impactHeader.html",
        cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><center><img  ng-src="{{row.getProperty(\'rl\') | dateformat1}}"</img></center></div>'
    }
]
```

Can any one please tell me how can I modify the function such that it returns only M values when M is selected from the drop down. and same for H and L.

Comment: can you provide a plunker

Comment: @YagizOzturk sorry I can't.. Actually I am new to angular JS and so to plunker.. will update question when Plunker is ready.. but can you please guide me how to deal with this?

Comment: have a look at the answer below, i tried to help at some point.

Answer (score 0):

In order to help in some way, i am posting a SO answer which is an alternative way of solving your problem.

It sure has better practices.

Have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528007/how-to-filter-the-ng-grid-by-dropdown-values).

In this question, ng-change is added to your element which is fully doable. According to a new value, you bind your grid again..

I used it in a project of mine. Here it is..

```
<input maxlength="34" type="text" ng-model="pollInfo.companyName" ng-change="updateIframe()" class="has-success form-control pull-left" placeholder="Anket Logo Yazısı" required id="companyName">
```

Ang get the change in controller

```
$scope.updateIframe = function() {
        var data=new Object();
        data.questions=$scope.questions;
        data.pollInfo=$scope.pollInfo;
        document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.updatedata(data);       
    };
```

You can do like this. In your method bind your grid. Again, this is not a best practice.
The best practice is that you do with $filter. But I need more info for your example to solve it.