# Ascending/Descending filter Strings on ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying out Ascending and Descending type of sorting in Angular JS with Strings

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ONwRTqftqQ6JUHNkMhpp?p=preview) The select box has  two options `Ascending` and `Descending`

when `Ascending` is chosen than the grid should output the values with Importance in order `L-M-H` stands for `Low-Medium-High` and similarly for `Descending` that is `H-M-L`

I have already asked these questions but sorry can't get my concepts right about sorting and filtering in Angular JS

**UPDATE**

I had implemented a part of it where I have sorted the contents in same order

[Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362548/angular-js-sort-grid-contents-based-on-dropdown-selection)
 Here i have used a drop down for selection. and the same drop down has two more options of `Ascending` and `Descending` for which I am trying to find out answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any non-hackish way of using an external `select` such as you show in your Plunker.

As for the sorting itself, you can create and use a custom sorting function:

```
var prioritySort = function(a, b){
    var priority = { L: 1, M: 2, H: 3 };
    if(priority[a] > priority[b]) return 1;
    if(priority[a] < priority[b]) return -1;
    return 0;
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enableSorting: true,
    showFilter: true,
    columnDefs: [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
    { field: 'age', displayName: 'Age' },
    { field: 'Importance', displayName: 'Importance', sortFn: prioritySort}]
};
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tj6OdqCiCBt0i8JyIKga?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry but I already have that done,, so this is no help to me.. :) thanks for efforts

Comment: You did not point this out in your question, nor was it evident in your Plunker. In fact, this seems to cover what you ask for in your question, minus the wiring up of the ascending/descending button. Please describe your questions more carefully.